# Problem connecting to localhost with watir

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer-8, watir

I have a set of cucumber tests that normally run fine against our site.  But if I make any changes and want to run the tests locally, the tests fail immediately, even before the initial page is finished loading.

I tried in IRB without cucumber and get the same error, using the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto("http://localhost:1234/somepath")

browser.text_field(:id, 'Username').set('jimbob')
```

Which fails with the following:

```
WIN32OLERuntimeError: unknown property or method `document'
    HRESULT error code:0x800706b5
      The interface is unknown.
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:467:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:467:in `document'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/container.rb:836:in `locate_input_element'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/input_elements.rb:5:in `locate'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/element.rb:55:in `assert_exists'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/input_elements.rb:366:in `set'
```

Versions:

- OS:      Windows 7
- Browser: IE8
- Ruby:    1.8.7 (I tried using 1.9.2, but it didn't have a problem)
- Watir:   1.7.1

Comment: Is that an exact copy/paste? You're missing a quote.

Comment: No it wasn't copy/paste...but thanks for the catch!  Looks like Adam Tegen has already updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run as Administrator on Windows 7 when using Watir against localhost.

Credit to http://chowamigo.blogspot.com/2010/03/setting-up-cucumber-to-use-watir-test.html

Comment: Ugh! Great catch! I can't believe _that_ was the hang up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same thing applies to Server2008 btw  gotta run the command line window as admin in order for watir to work correctly.  Something to do with IE security I'm sure.